how can i bypass this error msg: "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."?
i'm trying to make a event for service account without showing a consent screen for google calendar api. Here is my total code:
@Component
@Slf4j
public class GoogleApiClient {

    public GoogleApiClient(@Value("google_calendar/snapevent_api.json") String keyFileName) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        /*
         * Service account authentication
         */
        InputStream keyFile = ResourceUtils.getURL("classpath:" + keyFileName).openStream();
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(keyFile).createScoped(List.of(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR))
                .createDelegated("myserviceaccount"); // Google address where the service account was created (not for gcp Google account)

        NetHttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(transport, GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential).setApplicationName("snapEventCalendar").build();

        String calendarId = "mycalendarId";

        /*
         * Create a calendar event
         */
        Event event = new Event()
                .setSummary("test") // 일정 이름
                .setDescription("teststst"); // 일정 설명

        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2024-05-23T09:00:00-07:00");
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                .setTimeZone("Asia/Seoul");
        event.setStart(start);
        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2024-05-24T09:00:00-07:00");
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                .setTimeZone("Asia/Seoul");
        event.setEnd(end);

        // add an Event attendees
        EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
                new EventAttendee().setEmail("myaccount@gmail.com")
        };
        event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

        String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1"};
        event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

        EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
                new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
        };
        Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                .setUseDefault(false)
                .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
        event.setReminders(reminders);

        // execute an event
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
        log.debug("Event created: {}", event.getHtmlLink());
    }

well, after that, everything was fine such as making a specific event with target date except for inviting attendee, making reminders.
And here is the total error message Json format:
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "calendar",
      "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.",
      "reason": "forbiddenForServiceAccounts"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."
}

i already enabled G-suite domain delegation, but it didn't work. how can i fix it?
